# How to create a list using PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have following codes:

-------class------------

```
private class SystemHealthAlert implements Work {
        List<MonitorAlertInstance>  systemHealthAlertList; 
        private String queryString;
    //  private java.util.Date startDate;
    //  private java.util.Date endDate;

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {        
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);

            int index = 1;
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


            int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            while(rs.next())
            {   
                //String[] row = new String[columnCount];
                //results.set(index, element);
                //for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
              //  {
              //     row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
             //   }
                systemHealthAlertList.add(row);
            }       


            rs.close();
            ps.close();
        }
    }
```

---------Method-----------

```
public List<MonitorAlertInstance> getSystemHealthAlert(Long selectedSensorId) {
        List<MonitorAlertInstance>  systemHealthAlertList; 

        try {
            // Add SELECT with a nested select to get the 1st row
            String queryString = "select min(MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID) as MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID, description" +
                    "                      from ems.monitor_alert_instance  " +
                    "                          where description in (select description from monitor_alert_instance" +
                    "                            where co_mod_asset_id = " + selectedSensorId +
                    "                                               )" +
                    "                       group by description";

            SystemHealthAlert work = new SystemHealthAlert();
        //  work.coModAssetId = coModAssetId;
            work.queryString = queryString;

            getSession().doWork(work);

            systemHealthAlertList = work.systemHealthAlertList;

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        //  log.error("getMostRecentObservationId() failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
        //log.info("End");
        return systemHealthAlertList;
    }
```

My query returns three rows from DB. How can I return systemHealthAlertList from the class that will have all the three rows of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `execute`, you should fill your `List<MonitorAlertInstance> systemHealthAlertList` with instances of `MonitorAlertInstance`. Create a new instance of `MonitorAlertInstance` inside the `while` loop where you retrieve the data:

```
//You don't need this line, remove it
//int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(rs.next()) {
    //create a new instance of MonitorAlertInstance per ResultSet row
    MonitorAlertInstance monitor = new MonitorAlertInstance();
    //set the fields from the ResultSet in your MonitorAlertInstance fields
    //since I don't know the fields of this class, I would use field1 and field2 as examples
    monitor.setField1(rs.getInt(1));
    monitor.setField2(rs.getString(2));
    //and on...
    systemHealthAlertList.add(monitor);
}
```

---

Apart from this problem, you should initialize your `List<MonitorAlertInstance>  systemHealthAlertList` variable before use it:

```
systemHealthAlertList = new ArrayList<MonitorAlertInstance>();
while(rs.next()) {
    //content from previous code...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add all the fields from MonitorAlertInstance class?

Comment: @Novis fill the necessary fields in the class. If this means to fill every field, then yes, you should add all of them.

Comment: What do you mean by fill the necessary fields? I have 13 fields in MonitorALertInstance class.

Comment: @Novis I mean that if you only retrieve two fields from database, then you will just fill 2 fields in your class. If you retrieve 13 fields from database, then you will have to fill the 13 fields in your class.

Comment: I got two values from DB and set those two fields inside while loop. But it is getting null pointer exception in the line:  systemHealthAlertList.add(monitor);

Any idea?

Comment: That solves the exception. Thanks. Still one more question. I am trying to set another values like following:
  monitor.getMonitorAlert().setMonitorAlertId(rs.getLong(3));

MonitorAlertInstance class holds MonitorAlert  class. In the query I am getting three values. Those are MonitorAlertInstanceId, description, and MonitorAlertId. When I am tryng to set the value of
MonitorAlertId then it is showing error. Any idea.

Comment: @Novis looks like `monitor.getMonitorAlert()` returns `null`, which means you need to initialize the `monitorAlert` variable in the constructor of your `MonitorAlertInstance` class. Please try to understand the exception messages to try to post a solution.

Comment: yes, monitor.getMonitorAlert() returns null. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Novis I already explained how to do it in my last comment. Looks like you need to review Java basics...

Answer (score 0):

Define a class/bean to hold the data from one given row. Loop through your rows, and create one instance of that class for each row you have. Add these instances to some List. Return the List of these 3 instances.

Comment: OK, then OP just needs to populate the instances and return the list containing them.